# Flash Player Internals Diagram

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Looking for a simple diagram showing the constituent parts of the Flash player like AVM1,AVM2,graphics renderer, text layout engine, video player, etc.  Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may read [Flash Player Mental Model - The Elastic Racetrack](http://www.onflex.org/ted/2005/07/flash-player-mental-model-elastic.php), which is for AVM1. Someone edited a [AVM2 version](http://www.craftymind.com/2008/04/18/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/) too.

Here is [a whitepaper on the execution order](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/orderofoperations/).

Answer (score 1):

Check at http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2008-develop/flash-player-internals-by-jim-corbett-and-lee-thomason/